# The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver> error for FluentWait Class through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fluentwait

I am working with `Selenium Standalone Server 3.0.1`. I am trying to add an `Explicit Wait` to my code to detect an element through xpath when the element becomes visible. In order to get some Java help I looked out for the source code for  `Selenium Standalone Server 3.0.1` but was unable to find it. I found the source code in `selenium-java-2.53.1` release. I downloaded it and found `selenium-java-2.53.1-srcs` and added to my `Eclipse IDE`. From the help of `FluentWait`, I simply copy pasted the code in my `Eclipse IDE` and changed the variable names.

The sample code in documentation is like:

```
   // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
      }
    });
```

But when I implement this code, simply copy pasting it:

```
       Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
           .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

       WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()        {
         public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
           return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='WebDriver']"));
         }
       });
```

I am getting an error on `FluentWait` Class as `The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver>`

Here is the list of my imports:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
    import com.google.common.base.Function;
```

Can anyone help me out please?

---

### Update

Added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/selenium-webdriver-3-0-1-eclipse-java-chrome-selenium-showing-error-for-fluen/49690732#49690732) with respect to the modified constructor of **FluentWait** in **Selenium v3.11.0**

Comment: Did you try the example out of the docs? https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Comment: @JeffC Thanks. I can see some difference between the documentation provided by  selenium-java-2.53.1 src code and the documentation provided in the URL you shared. While in selenium-java-2.53.1 src code the creating an object is <<-- Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver) -->> but the link documentation says it as <<-- Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)  -->>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify expected condition inside the wait below is the modified code that could solve your problem.

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

public class DummyClass
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        until(new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() 
        {
            public Boolean apply(WebElement element)
            {
                return element.getText().endsWith("04");
            }

            private void until(Function<WebElement, Boolean> function)
            {
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sample Post2"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code or check below code if it could help?
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
               .withTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .pollingEvery(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         
         // start waiting for given element
         wait.until(new ElementWaitCondition(browser, query));

Comment: Thanks, if I provide, << FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)>> Eclipse IDE is still showing me error as ``The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver>``

Comment: I am able to implement without any error, i am using Selenium-java 3.0.1 and server 3.0.1

Comment: Thanks Sir. To update you, as of now I have added the following import  ``import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;``  if I try to import ``import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;`` Eclipse IDE shows me an error as "The import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait conflicts with a type defined in the same file". Any other suggestions please?

Comment: I did two changes, First I deleted my class file "FluentWait.class" which I suspect was referring to the interface. Created a new class file "FluentWaitExample" and I have added both the imports ``import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;`` and 
``import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;`` Still I get an error at  << new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver) >> The error says ``FluentWait cannot be resolved to a type``

Comment: Well, just cleaned up the environment & tried to build with the error & the error is gone. It have executed successfully. Thank you so much for your time & effort Sir.

Answer (score 3):

With the availability of *Selenium v3.11.0* the constructor of [FluentWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) have changed. Now the argument type for `withTimeout` and `pollingEvery` is [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Here is the modified implementation :

```
import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class Fluent_Wait {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
            // for its presence once every 500 milliseconds.
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

            WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB, it eliminated message: " Warning:() java: withTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) in org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait has been deprecated"

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same error, later I noticed that I was using the class name as `fluentwait`. After changing the class name it was working fine.

Comment: What did you change the class name to, sorry I am new to this area?

Comment: @topsoftwarepro 
Change it to any another name other than 'FluentWait', For Example u can use Fluent_Wait

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the other method implementation:

```
withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
```

The form `withTimeout(Duration timeOut)`
is still used and non-deprecated one

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same error that `The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver>` but i noticed a silly mistake that my main class was also named as FuentWait and it was not generic. I changed its name and error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error since I named the class 'FluentWait' that I created in eclipse to implement fluent wait. Try renaming the class to a different name.