# method until in the type Wait is not applicable error is thrown when trying to use FluentWait .until method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use FluentWait in my Selenium Java automation.

When I used the until method, I get the following error
the method until(Function in the type Wait is not applicable for the argument(new Function(){}

```
public WebElement fluentWaitForElement() {
    Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    WebElement waitingElement = fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("ButtonID"));
    }
   }
 );
}
```

I also tried the solution in another post. But, I still get the same error

```
fluentWaitwait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
    @Override public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.ID("ButtonID"));
        }
    }
);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1-\[Eclipse-Java-Chrome\]: Selenium showing error for FluentWait Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/selenium-webdriver-3-0-1-eclipse-java-chrome-selenium-showing-error-for-fluen)

Comment: Still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to use `new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>()`.

You can either use `ExpectedCondtion<T>` class which `extends Function<WebDriver, T>;` or use `lambda expression`.

Expected Condition:

```
.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                //return Boolean value
                return null;
            }

        });
```

Lambda Expression:

```
.until(driver -> {
    return null; 
//return any type parameter you want. Lambda Expression takes care of what type you return
}
```

Additional "flaw" in your code is:

```
Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

`Wait` cannot be parametrized with `WebDriver` as it's not generic. Change it to `FluentWait<WebDriver>`