# How to remove deprecation warning on timeout and polling in Selenium Java Client v3.11.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fluentwait

Below is my code which is showing as deprecated after I have been updated the Selenium Webdriver version to 3.11.0.

```
    private Wait<WebDriver> mFluentWait(WebDriver pDriver) {
    Wait<WebDriver> gWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(pDriver).withTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);   
    return gWait;
}
```

Showing deprecated warning in `withTimeout` and `pollingEvery` section in the code.

How can I rewrite this code so that I can remove the deprecated warning.

Since am new to selenium am not sure about the change. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1-\[Eclipse-Java-Chrome\]: Selenium showing error for FluentWait Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/selenium-webdriver-3-0-1-eclipse-java-chrome-selenium-showing-error-for-fluen)

Comment: @DebanjanB I am not getting any errors on executing, the `withTimeout` and `pollingEvery` section in the code is showing as deprecated. When I referred the selenium documents , it is showing in the deprecated lists. So I want to remove the deprecated parts in the code and want to rewrite the method. I think you have understood the difference between the question you mentioned and I have asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Grasshopper 's answer points us to the exact modified **constructor** of **FluentWait** and your requirement of removing the deprecation warning from **withTimeout** and **pollingEvery** fields. Incase you are facing further difficulty you can use the line of code below :

```
import java.time.Duration;
//lines of code
Wait<WebDriver> gWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(pDriver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments  error for FluentWait Class through Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/the-type-fluentwait-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-w/49690732#49690732)

Comment: This is what am exactly looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

Check the source code of [FluentWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java) which mentions to use the methods using Duration as arguments instead.

1. withTimeout - Use the `withTimeout(Duration duration)` method.
2. pollingEvery - Use the `pollingEvery(Duration duration)` method.

Answer (score 6):

you can use following lines of code:

```
  Wait<Browser> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(*timeToWaitInSec*))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(*TimeToTryinMillisec*))
            .ignoring(WebDriverException.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade to Selenium 4, few of the old methods have been deprecated of which Fluent wait is part of.

Use the below code in the similar order for seamless execution:

```
 Wait<Browser> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(*timeToWaitInSec*))
            .ignoring(WebDriverException.class)
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(*TimeToTryinMillisec*));
```

Also refer for below article for the other changes/upgrade in Selenium 4.

https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4-migration/