# The type Function is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver, WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, fluentwait

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    }
});
```

Tried to work on Fluent wait implementation with Selenium 3.141.59 but getting the specified compile time error. I am mainly concerned with "new Function method"

[The type FluentWait is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver> error for FluentWait Class through Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/the-type-fluentwait-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-w)

I don't believe this is a duplicate. Question may sound the same but none of the solutions worked for me.

Error Shown:

```
The type Function is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver, WebElement>
```

Comment: Perhaps you are not importing the correct Function interface (or another interface/class of the same name are hiding it).

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to do with this explicit wait?

You could use a pre-defined Expected Condition:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("q")));
```

The reason you are having problems is that you are trying to create a new instance of a Function which is an interface, you can't do that.  You could refactor the above ExpectedCondition into:

```
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    }
});
```

It looks quite close to your attempt, but it's not very readable or reusable.  I would suggest that you create your own helper class with your own expected conditions in that looks like the standard [ExpectedConditions class supplied by Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java).